# Showing values of parameters packs in gdb

Tags: c++, c++11, gdb, variadic-templates

How can one see the values of a parameter pack in a variadic function in gdb?

Sample code (VariadicDebug.cpp):

```
template <typename... Ts> int Do(int a, Ts... ts)
{
  // Add breakpoint here. a can be seen using 'print a' but how to show ts???
  return a;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  return Do(0, "Hello world!", 88.9);
}
```

Compile with

```
g++ --std=c++11 -O0 -g VariadicDebug.cpp
```

And run gdb:

```
$ gdb ./a.exe
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.9
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-pc-msys".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from ./a.exe...done.
(gdb) break VariadicDebug.cpp:4
Breakpoint 1 at 0x100401760: file VariadicDebug.cpp, line 4.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /c/Data/tests/a.exe
[New Thread 8008.0x1dd0]
[New Thread 8008.0x2898]
[New Thread 8008.0x26f0]
[New Thread 8008.0x1498]

Breakpoint 1, Do<char const*, double> (a=0) at VariadicDebug.cpp:4
4         return a;
(gdb) info args
a = 0
```

As you can see: It only gives the value for ***a*** not for ***ts***.

**EDIT:** gdb: 7.9, g++: 4.9.2 on MSYS2

**EDIT**: ubuntu 15.04 (g++: 4.9.2, gdb: 7.9, binutils: 2.25) gives same result

**EDIT**: objdump --debugging resulted in:

```
 <1><81>: Abbrev Number: 7 (DW_TAG_subprogram)
    <82>   DW_AT_external    : 1
    <82>   DW_AT_name        : (indirect string, offset: 0x0): FindItEasy<char const*, double>
    <86>   DW_AT_decl_file   : 1
    <87>   DW_AT_decl_line   : 1
    <88>   DW_AT_linkage_name: (indirect string, offset: 0x3a): _Z10FindItEasyIIPKcdEEiiDpT_
    <8c>   DW_AT_type        : <0x67>
    <90>   DW_AT_low_pc      : 0x400529
    <98>   DW_AT_high_pc     : 0x15
    <a0>   DW_AT_frame_base  : 1 byte block: 9c         (DW_OP_call_frame_cfa)
    <a2>   DW_AT_GNU_all_call_sites: 1
    <a2>   DW_AT_sibling     : <0xdc>
 <2><a6>: Abbrev Number: 8 (DW_TAG_GNU_template_parameter_pack)
    <a7>   DW_AT_name        : Ts
    <aa>   DW_AT_sibling     : <0xb9>
 <3><ae>: Abbrev Number: 9 (DW_TAG_template_type_param)
    <af>   DW_AT_type        : <0xdc>
 <3><b3>: Abbrev Number: 9 (DW_TAG_template_type_param)
    <b4>   DW_AT_type        : <0xe7>
 <3><b8>: Abbrev Number: 0
 <2><b9>: Abbrev Number: 3 (DW_TAG_formal_parameter)
    <ba>   DW_AT_name        : (indirect string, offset: 0x20): first
    <be>   DW_AT_decl_file   : 1
    <bf>   DW_AT_decl_line   : 1
    <c0>   DW_AT_type        : <0x67>
    <c4>   DW_AT_location    : 2 byte block: 91 6c      (DW_OP_fbreg: -20)
 <2><c7>: Abbrev Number: 10 (DW_TAG_GNU_formal_parameter_pack)
    <c8>   DW_AT_decl_file   : 1
    <c9>   DW_AT_decl_line   : 1
 <3><ca>: Abbrev Number: 11 (DW_TAG_formal_parameter)
    <cb>   DW_AT_type        : <0xdc>
    <cf>   DW_AT_location    : 2 byte block: 91 60      (DW_OP_fbreg: -32)
 <3><d2>: Abbrev Number: 11 (DW_TAG_formal_parameter)
    <d3>   DW_AT_type        : <0xe7>
    <d7>   DW_AT_location    : 2 byte block: 91 58      (DW_OP_fbreg: -40)
 <3><da>: Abbrev Number: 0
 <2><db>: Abbrev Number: 0
```

Seems that the arguments are in here (last two *DW_TAG_formal_parameter*) but without their respective names!

**EDIT**: Compiling with -c and running objdump on the generated .o file also gives the same output. So does this mean it's my g++ that is doing this wrong? (I would appreciate it to not compile it by myself :-) )

Comment: Same missing debug info with g++7 (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) and gdb (Ubuntu 8.1-0ubuntu3.2) on Ubuntu 18.04. However switching back to g++6 (Ubuntu 6.5.0-2ubuntu1~18.04) would work fine. All the tools are from the official apt. It seems that g++ is broken here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A trick that always works in gdb is pressing tab while expanding vars!

So if you type:

> gdb > print ts *tab*

you get

`ts#0`
`ts#1`

so to print your variable you simply go with:

> gdb > print 'ts#1'

Important to use the single quotes here!

Also

> gdb > info args

give me:

`a=0`
`ts#0 = 0x400d06 "Hello world!"`
`ts#1 = 88,900000000000006`

gdb version is: 7.9.1, compiler is 5.2.0

As requested:

I compiled aslo with older 4.9.2 gcc and run outdated gdb 7.7. Same results for me, it works also as explained here!

EDIT:
To find out to which side ( compiler vs. gdb ) the problem is related, you can try to read out the debug information manually:

Remark: I changed my function name to 'FindItEasy' and parms to 'First/Rest' so that I can search not for 2 letters here :-)

> objdump --debugging

```
    <158>   DW_AT_name        : (indirect string, offset: 0x18d): FindItEasy
    <15c>   DW_AT_decl_file   : 1
    <15d>   DW_AT_decl_line   : 14
    <15e>   DW_AT_prototyped  : 1
    <15e>   DW_AT_low_pc      : 0x400b6f
    <166>   DW_AT_high_pc     : 0x37
    <16e>   DW_AT_frame_base  : 1 byte block: 9c    (DW_OP_call_frame_cfa)
    <170>   DW_AT_GNU_all_call_sites: 1
    <170>   DW_AT_sibling     : <0x1f8>
 <2><174>: Abbrev Number: 7 (DW_TAG_formal_parameter)
    <175>   DW_AT_name        : (indirect string, offset: 0x59): first
    <179>   DW_AT_decl_file   : 1
    <17a>   DW_AT_decl_line   : 14
    <17b>   DW_AT_type        : <0x34>
    <17f>   DW_AT_location    : 0xbe (location list)
 <2><183>: Abbrev Number: 7 (DW_TAG_formal_parameter)
    <184>   DW_AT_name        : (indirect string, offset: 0x66): rest#0
    <188>   DW_AT_decl_file   : 1
    <189>   DW_AT_decl_line   : 14
    <18a>   DW_AT_type        : <0x6c>
    <18e>   DW_AT_location    : 0x10a (location list)
 <2><192>: Abbrev Number: 7 (DW_TAG_formal_parameter)
    <193>   DW_AT_name        : (indirect string, offset: 0x6d): rest#1
    <197>   DW_AT_decl_file   : 1
    <198>   DW_AT_decl_line   : 14
    <199>   DW_AT_type        : <0x2d>
    <19d>   DW_AT_location    : 0x169 (location list)
 <2><1a1>: Abbrev Number: 8 (DW_TAG_GNU_call_site)
    <1a2>   DW_AT_low_pc      : 0x400b89
    <1aa>   DW_AT_abstract_origin: <0x408>
    <1ae>   DW_AT_sibling     : <0x1ba>
```

You maybe can try to find the debug informations on your file.

Hint: Having the gdb and gcc version is not the complete truth. Both tools build up on top of binutils. And if binutils are outdated, it is possible that some debug infos ( like dwarf format ) are incomplete ). Maybe You can check out for that!

Comment: (See my edit for the versions of my tools): So it seems that this is new to gdb 7.9.1 or that g++ 4.9.2 does not export the necessary symbols :-(

Comment: So does MSYS2 makes a difference here???? I hardly could believe it...I will try it on Linux.

Comment: I added some hints to find the reason for the different behavior.

Comment: Okay...I tried on linux (Ubuntu 15.04; g++ 4.9.2, gdb 7.9, binutils 2.25) but it does not work. So I will look into the debug infos...

Comment: See my edit: More information about parameter packs...but no name 'rest'...

Comment: That is crazy! Maybe you can dig on which debug formats you are run on? Are you sure that actual binutils are involved while building the toolchain? I build all tools ( binutils/gcc/gdb) from source. No dependency to the system I run on and I know why :-) For that you should give building the binutils from scratch, build gcc on top of this and finally build gdb. Maybe this change something... Sorry, I can't see any other relation which we can go into.